# Unable to create vertex shader from cso file (created from fx file)

Tags: c++, uwp, directx-11

Shader successfully compiles to cso file at build time. But when I try to call CreateVertexShader - I get an error:

*D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader: Encoded Vertex Shader size doesn't match specified size.*

I set shader type "Effect(/fx)", entry point: "VS", shader model - 5.0.

I tried models 4.0, 4.1 - the error is different:

*D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader: Shader is corrupt or in an unrecognized format.*

My code:

```
ID3DBlob* pVSBlob = NULL;
HRESULT hr = D3DReadFileToBlob((WCHAR*)name.c_str(), &pVSBlob);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return;
}

hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &vertexShader);
```

Device features:

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
};
```

My shader code:

```
cbuffer cbTrunkCutMode : register(b1)
{
    float HighlightAdj;
};

cbuffer cbChangesEveryFrame : register(b0)
{
    matrix Matrices[2];
};


struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 VertexPosition_modelspace : POSITION;
    float3 vertexNormal_modelspace : NORMAL;
    float age : AGE;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 Position_worldspace : WSPOSITION;
    float3 Normal_cameraspace : NORMAL;
    float3 EyeDirection_cameraspace : EYEDIRECTION;
    float age : AGE;
};

PS_INPUT VS(VS_INPUT input)
{
    PS_INPUT output;
    output.Position= mul(Matrices[1], float4(input.VertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0));
    output.Position_worldspace = input.VertexPosition_modelspace;

    float3 vertexPosition_cameraspace = mul(Matrices[0], float4(input.VertexPosition_modelspace,1.0)).xyz;
    output.EyeDirection_cameraspace = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) - vertexPosition_cameraspace;

    output.Normal_cameraspace = mul((float3x3)Matrices[0], input.vertexNormal_modelspace); // Only correct if ModelMatrix does not scale the model ! Use its inverse transpose if not.
    output.age = input.age;

    return output;
}

static const float3 LightPosition = normalize(float3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    float3 MaterialDiffuseColor = float3(0.05,0.3,0.05);
    float3 MaterialAmbientColor = float3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
    float3 MaterialSpecularColor = 0.5*MaterialDiffuseColor;

    float3 n = normalize(input.Normal_cameraspace);
    float3 l = LightPosition;
    float cosTheta = clamp(dot(n,l), 0.0,1.0);

    float3 E = normalize(input.EyeDirection_cameraspace);
    float3 R = reflect(-l,n);
    float cosAlpha = clamp(dot(E,R), 0.0,1.0);

    return float4((
        float3(HighlightAdj - input.age, -HighlightAdj, -input.age - HighlightAdj) +
        MaterialAmbientColor +
        MaterialDiffuseColor * cosTheta +
        MaterialSpecularColor * pow(cosAlpha, 5.0)),1);
}
```

Comment: You should probably set shader type to *Vertex Shader (/vs)* when compiling.

Comment: It works. But I have the both shaders in the same file and Pixel shader don't compile now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio's build-in HLSL build rules are useful for small projects, but there is one concept to keep in mind: Visual Studio's project system assumes each source file is used to generate one compiled object file (in this case `.cso`).

To make this work when you have combined shader types in the same file, you just need to create some additional files.  For example:

First file is `MyShader.hlsli`. This would contain your combined shader code for VS & PS

The second file `MyShaderVS.hlsl`

```
#include "MyShader.hlsli"
```

The third file `MyShaderPS.hlsl`

```
#include "MyShader.hlsli"
```

You then set the VS Project build properties up to build the `MyShaderVS.hlsl` as a Vertex Shader (`/vs`). You build the `MyShaderPS.hlsl` as a Pixel Shader (`/ps)`. Set the Entry-points appropriate for each one.

The result will get your original shader code built more than once.

> The Effects file system that had one `.fx` that compiled into lots of shader blobs all in one compiled object works with the Visual Studio system, but (a) the compiler support is deprecated, and (b) you need a runtime library to use it from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/FX11). Using HLSL shader types instead is recommended. See [the wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/FX11/wiki#disclaimer).